# How should I make a jump-timing game's character static on screen?

Tags: camera, python, platformer, pygame

I decided to learn Pygame and try to make a simple game inspired by Google's T-rex jump game. However, I stumbled upon a problem that I can not seem to figure out: How can I implement a scroller/camera that can keep up with my character and platform?

Now it just disappears off the screen. I have made it so the platform moves to the right with the same speed as the character. Here is a GIF of what it looks like at the moment:

[image]

Is this the best way to do it for a game like this where speed of the character is always constant or is there a better way that will make adding obstacles in the future more easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overthinking it.  For the dinosaur game, you need 2 sprites (don't worry about the pterodactyl or different sized cactuses yet):

- Dino

The dino doesn't move left/right - he stays in the same spot on the screen, and pressing space only makes him jump up - gravity makes him fall down.  The "ground" is just the y coordinate where you make him stop.  Draw a line there using pygame.draw.line()

- Cactus

A cactus spawns with an x position > screen_width, and its x_velocity is < 0.  That will make it look like it moves across the screen from right to left.  When a cactus has an x_pos < 0, you delete it.

That's it. There's no need for a camera or moving platforms, etc.  The illusion is that the dino is running, but really it's just the cactuses.  The illusion is improved with some small clouds that move at a slightly slower speed than the cactus does.

Comment: Ohhh I see. Think I know how I can approach this now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Pygame but it appears as though your moving the terrain away from the camera. Maybe not the best way of wording it, but you should just move the terrain to the left keeping the T-rex in a constant spot in the X axis, then when you just you simply move it in the Y-axis when jumping  while still moving the terrain to the left (at a constant speed or one that increases over time). that way it appears as though there is movement in the T-rex while in reality the ground is just moving under it.